# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '####' when running .py script in command line

Tags: python

Here's the simplified demo.

```
project-dir
    |__dir1
         |__dir2
              |__mod1
              |    |__func1.py
              |    |__func2.py
              |__a.py
              |__b.py
```

```
# /dir1/dir2/mod1/func1.py
def bar():
    print('this is func `bar` in `func1`')
```

```
# /dir1/dir2/mod1/func2.py
def foo():
    print('this is func `foo` in `func2`')
```

```
# /dir1/dir2/b.py
def spam():
    print('this is func `spam` in `b`')
```

```
# /dir1/dir2/a.py
from dir1.dir2.b import spam
from dir1.dir2.mod1.func1 import bar
from dir1.dir2.mod1.func2 import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('this is `a`)
    spam()
    bar()
    foo()
```

When I run this script `a.py` in command line as `D:\project-dir>python dir1/dir2/a.py`, the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir1'` occurs. But it works out when running this script `a.py` directly in IDE. How to correctly run this script in command line ?

Comment: depending on python version you use, might need to add `__init__.py` file under each module (a dummy one).

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 and following @KetZoomer 's answer without added `__init__.py` works while some `Unresolved reference '###'` remains.

Comment: Yeah, the Unresolved reference happens since you don't have an ```__init__.py```, read @Abhilash 's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in `a.py`:

```py
# /dir1/dir2/a.py
from b import spam
from mod1.func1 import bar
from mod1.func2 import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('this is `a`)
    spam()
    bar()
    foo()
```

Python allows you to import something in the local directory.

Edit:

You said you were getting errors. You might need to include a dummy `__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, there's some syntax wranings in IDE, such as `Unresolved reference 'b'` though. How to eliminate this problem ?

Comment: @TAOGS, please select the correct answer (the check mark), thanks